# Google Map directions on iPad

Tags: google, maps

When looking for directions, Google Maps says "first of three suggested routes."  It shows the first, but I can find no way of finding out what the **other** two suggested routes are.  I've searched the screen and can see no way.  How do I do it?

Comment: This question _may_ be a better fit at [apple.se].

Answer (score 1):

[image: iPhone Maps.app Screenshot]

Yes, I know this isn't an iPad screenshot, but I don't currently have iOS 5 on my iPad :). Regardless, the function is the same, you can tap the route labels in order to view the alternative routes. You may need to zoom in or out to see them.